# To generates dynamically textboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamically-generated

I want to generate dynamically textbox in asp.net and c#.
This code works only once, but I want any time click the button, two textboxes added.

```
private void CreateTextBox(string ID)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = ID;
    txt.Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
    txt.AutoPostBack = false;
    TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
    txt2.ID = ID + "s";
    txt2.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
    txt2.AutoPostBack = false;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp&nbsp"));
    Panel1.Controls.Add(txt2);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

}


  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        CreateTextBox("txtTag-" + index.ToString());
        index ++;
}
```

index is global static int variable.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ControlRenderer instead of this, such as this:

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textName;
    textName = new TextBox();
    textName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textName_TextChanged);

    string divContect = ControlRenderer(divTextBox);
    divTextBox.InnerHtml = divContect + ControlRenderer(textName);
}

protected void textName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public string ControlRenderer(Control control)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    control.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(writer));
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work, but what's the TextChanged and ControlRenderer?

Comment: TextChanged is an event that is provided by the textbox in case u want some code to be executed when any text in the textbox is changed by the user then u can put it in the method `textName_TextChanged` if you dont want to handle this event then simply remove the method and the line `textName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textName_TextChanged);`

Answer (score 1):

U need to learn the Page Life Cycle of asp.net. 
Http is a stateless protocol The server does not remember anything about the previous requests

Y don't u Learn about using `Session` and then keep track of the index in the `Session` variable

Comment: I know session but how use that? Can give me an example, please?
I should add panel in session or textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
int index = 1;
while(index <=2)
{
   CreateTextBox("txtTag-" + index.ToString());
   index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls pragmatically only during the page's initialization stage, see [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)